# How to store scraped data from scrapy into mongoDB in a tree-structured way?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, scrapy

I am doing a task on storing data to MongoDB in tree structure. I have scraped data I wanted with scrapy successfully. Also I know that in MongoDB one can store data in a tree structure for example,

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "dbm", parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", parent: "Books" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", parent: null } )
```

So I thought by using pymongo I could do the similar job but it turned out that I can not.

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log

class CategoryPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
                                         settings['MONGODB_PORT']
                                         )
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        valid = True
        for data in item:
            if not data:
                valid = False
                raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
        if valid:

            self.collection.insert( { _id: "MongoDB",parent:"Databases" } ) 
            log.msg("question added to mongodb database!",
                    level=log.DEBUG,spider = spider)

        return item
```

The code above did not work.The error shows that _id is not defined. If I do like "_id" then it works but I think that will not do the tree function.

My question is how could I store tree-structured data into mongodb in pymongo?

Comment: What is your question. If you are asking opinions, you are on wrong forum.

Comment: @Saleem Hi Sorry I have not made it clear,I want to write code in pymongo to store tree-structured data to mongodb.but I do not figure out a way.